# Puppet: Crons via Hiera?

Tags: cron, puppet, hiera

I am trying to use hiera for my crons. Unfortunately this is not working with `cron_core`?

```
# common.yaml
---
my_module::cron::job::multiple:
  'my_cronjobs':
    jobs:
      # job1
      - {
          minute: 30,
          hour: 10,
          date: '*',
          month: '*',
          weekday: '*',
          user: user,
          command: '/bin/sleep 120',
          description: 'sleep for 2 min',
        }
      # job2
      - {
          minute: 0,
          hour: 11,
          date: '*',
          month: '*',
          weekday: '*',
          user: user,
          command: '/bin/sleep 60',
          description: 'sleep for 1 min',
        }
```

In my class I've tried

```
class my_module(){
    # enable crons
    include cron
}
```

But then it fails with `Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::cron`

Is there a way to solve this with `puppetlabs/cron_core`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things to note. First, you don't need to use `cron_core`. The `cron` resource type is included as standard. Second, `cron` is a resource type, not a class, so you can't `include` it.

If you want to create cron jobs using Hiera, try using the `create_resources` function. Restructure your Hiera to look like

```
my_module::cron::job::multiple:
 'sleep for 2 minutes': {
          minute: 30,
          hour: 10,
          date: '*',
          month: '*',
          weekday: '*',
          user: user,
          command: '/bin/sleep 120',
          description: 'sleep for 2 min',
        }
  'sleep for 1 minute': {
          minute: 0,
          hour: 11,
          date: '*',
          month: '*',
          weekday: '*',
          user: user,
          command: '/bin/sleep 60',
          description: 'sleep for 1 min',
        }
```

and you'll then be able to add the resources using

```
$cron_job_hash = lookup('my_module::cron::job::multiple', Hash, 'hash', {})
create_resources('cron', $cron_job_hash)
```